# Tiki: Unexpected return from trackerlib -> get_item_creators

Tags: tiki-wiki

I upgraded my tiki from 15.4 to 16.2. Everything runs fine. The problem is the site registration does not work. I have a tracker to extend my user information. In the tracker, I created a field called "Network" that allows the users to choose a group that them want to be in. Hence, they won't see each other content due to different group permission. This registration broke. The error message showed:

> Cannot add nonexistent user xxx to group students

I found out the problem was that there is a change in trackerlib.php line 3671. Instead of returning "null", it now returns an empty array().

```
else {
    return array();
}
```

In GroupSelector.php, line 124, the condition check

```
if (empty ($creators))) $creators=array($user);
```

This if will never be executed since the function now return an array not null. Hence causing the problem that no one can be registered if they choose a group in the registration form.

Propose solution, change the if condition in line 124 to:

```
if (empty($creators[0]))
```

Comment: Are you asking help here or are you somehow using your question as a bug report?

Comment: Indeed, seems a bit like a bug report and a fix is on it's way (see my comment below), so in the future the place to report bugs is https://dev.tiki.org/File-a-bug - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My fix has now been [improved](https://sourceforge.net/p/tikiwiki/code/63201) by our colleague kroky6 (thanks!) and is now in the 16.x branch, so you can test it by using the 16.x nightly tarball from [here](https://dev.tiki.org/Daily-Build#x_current_stable_) tomorrow and will be in 16.3 (and 17.0 onwards) *coming soon*...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the actual 16.x version (dev branch) of this file (lib/core/Tracker/Field/GroupSelector.php) ?

https://sourceforge.net/p/tikiwiki/code/HEAD/tree/branches/16.x/lib/core/Tracker/Field/GroupSelector.php

Chances are, this is fixed already. :)

Bernard

Comment: No, it hadn't been fixed yet, so i just (hopefully) fixed it in http://sourceforge.net/p/tikiwiki/code/63182 for Tiki 17 and will backport it to 16 if it looks ok (i couldn't reproduce it exactly) - i did it slightly differently to your suggestion to cover more types of "empty"